# Total number of pages in a PDF document

Tags: matlab, pdf

MATLAB provides the [`extractFileText`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/textanalytics/ref/extractfiletext.html) function which allows us to read text from PDF files, among other file formats, and save the extracted text as a string.

We can pass an extra argument to this function in order to extract text from specific pages of the document.

For example, to extract the text from pages 3, 5 and 7 from the sample `exampleSonnets.pdf` file:

```
str = extractFileText("exampleSonnets.pdf", 'Pages', [3 5 7]);
```

This function, however, does not provide a way of finding out the total number of pages that the PDF document contains *beforehand*.

So if we happen to do something like:

```
str = extractFileText("exampleSonnets.pdf", 'Pages', [99 100]);
```

The following error is thrown:

```
Error using extractFileText (line 95)
No page 100 in file. Maximum page number: 47.
```

Warning us that we have requested a page number that exceeds the actual total number of pages in the document.

This is fine.

However, how can I know the total number of pages in a PDF document *beforehand*, without triggering the error, so that I can safely narrow my searches to the maximum page number?

Is there a function for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way that ould let you do this. But you can use [`try/catch`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) to handle the situation directly without knowing the number of pages beforehand.

If you do need to know the number of pages beforehand you could just iterate through the pages until you hit an error that you do handle using `try/catch` (works for small pdfs) or implement e.g. a binary search in a similar way.

Comment: This is a very nice workaround! I turned your idea into code and posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54169977/3599179). Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

[flawr's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54169464/3599179) is actually very clever!

In fact, since the maximum page number is contained in the error message, we can trigger the exception (asking for any ridiculously big page number on purpose), catch it, and then parse the error message to recover the maximum page number.

```
No page 100 in file. Maximum page number: 47.
                                           ^
                                   This is all we need
```

So we don't even need to iterate through every page of the document :)

I went ahead and made this simple `numpages` function:

```
function [num] = numpages(filename)

% Queried page number. Any big number should do.
bignum = 1e6;

try
    extractFileText(filename, 'Pages', bignum);
catch ME
    if strcmp(ME.identifier, 'textanalytics:extractFileText:NoSuchPage')
        % Extract the Maximum page number from the exception message.
        num = str2double(extractBetween(ME.message, "number: ", "."));
    else
        % Not the exception we are interested in. Rethrow it.
        rethrow(ME);
    end
end

end
```

Test case:

```
>> numpages("exampleSonnets.pdf")

ans =

    47
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

Another, more elegant but maybe more computationally heavy, option would be to pass through Java using PDFBox:

**SOLUTION 1 (VERY SUBOPTIMAL)**

```
% Paths
root=pwd;

% add class
javaaddpath(fullfile(root,'pdfbox-app-2.0.29.jar'))

% load PDF

pdfdoc = org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
pdfdoc.close;

pdfDataStore = matlab.io.datastore.DsFileReader(targetPdf);
pdfBytes=read(pdfDataStore,pdfDataStore.Size);
pdfdoc=pdfdoc.load(pdfBytes);

% split PDF
splitting = org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.Splitter;
pdfdoc.isEncrypted;

pages=splitting.split(pdfdoc);
numOfPages=pages.size;
```

The only catch is that splitting the document to count the pages can be very consuming for big pdfs

---

**SOLUTION 2**

```
% Paths
root=pwd;

% add class
javaaddpath(fullfile(root,'pdfbox-app-2.0.29.jar'))

% load PDF

pdfdoc = org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
pdfdoc.close;

pdfDataStore = matlab.io.datastore.DsFileReader(targetPdf);
pdfBytes=read(pdfDataStore,pdfDataStore.Size);
pdfdoc=pdfdoc.load(pdfBytes);

numOfPages=pdfdoc.getNumberOfPages()
```

**EDIT**: updated the code to fit version 2.0.29

**EDIT 2** added a better (?) solution that does not need to split the document.

Comment: 0.7.3 is over 10 years old. Don't use it.

Comment: i'm updating the code to 2.0.29